# How to fix this ceiling crack

Tags: drywall, crack

Removed a (non load bearing) wall.
I did not use dry wall tape and now this has happened. What is the best way to remedy this?

Are there products like flexible compound that are sandable?

[image]

Comment: I can't see the crack in that small, distant photo. Is it actually cracked, or is it just a poor skim job?

Comment: It is cracked. Small, but cracked.

Comment: I suspect your problem will be a repair that matches the texture.  You could try a very elastic latex caulk, like Big Stretch.